# Rename records in multiple columns based on another data frame

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                 y = c(1,3,4,1,3,4,1,3,4),
                 z = c(6,3,7,8,2,3,0,1,2))
```

I'd like to rename values in columns x and y based on mapping contained in another data frame:

```
df.aux <- data.frame(id = c(0,1,2,3,4),
                     desc = c('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four))
```

to obtain:

```
      x     y z
1   one   one 6
2   one three 3
3   one  four 7
4 three   one 8
5 three three 2
6 three  four 3
7  four   one 0
8  four three 1
9  four  four 2
```

Note, that the mapping in df.aux may contain more levels than in df. I can do the mapping by changing the column name df$x to df$id, do the merge of two df's and then repeat it for df$y. But it's very clumsy, so there must be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **match** function to do the mapping:

```
df.new <- data.frame(x=df.aux$desc[match(df$x, df.aux$id)], y=df.aux$desc[match(df$y, df.aux$id)], z=df$z)
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you had many columns over which you needed to swap out the values, you could do something like this:

`solution <- apply(df, c(1,2), function(x) df.aux[df.aux$id == x, 2])`

Answer (score 1):

The `factor` function to allows direct assignment the of mappings and labels.

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,4),
+                  y = c(1,3,4,1,3,4,1,3,4),
+                  z = c(6,3,7,8,2,3,0,1,2))

> df.aux <- data.frame(id = c(0,1,2,3,4), desc = c('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'))
```

```
> df$x <- factor(df$x, levels = df.aux$id, labels = df.aux$desc)
> df$y <- factor(df$y, levels = df.aux$id, labels = df.aux$desc)
> df
      x     y z
1   one   one 6
2   one three 3
3   one  four 7
4 three   one 8
5 three three 2
6 three  four 3
7  four   one 0
8  four three 1
9  four  four 2
```

if `df.aux` is too huge for this to work quickly, you could subset it first with

```
df.aux[df.aux$id %in% union(df$x, df$y),]
```

Comment: Interesting. Accepted @Enrique 's answer because was first, but this works perfectly too.